# Retrieving I/O access time from task_io_accounting in Linux

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-kernel

I need to collect I/O access time information for a particular task (i.e., decoding a video frame) using Linux kernel information "task_io_accounting". [Here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/task_io_accounting.h), I found a header file that describes a structure corresponding to "task_io_accounting". However, I'm not sure how to use this to gather I/O access time information.

Could someone please assist me with this and point me into the right direction?.

Comment: An xy problem. The first thing you find is not necessarily the best.

Comment: I agree with stark -- I don't see how you're going to find out *access time information* using these -- but IO statistics are available in `/proc/PID/io` pseudofile for the process `PID`, and in `/proc/PID/task/TID/io` per thread; these are Linux-specific kernel-provided pseudofiles so are always in the C/POSIX locale.